# Accidental hydrolysis of tert-butyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Yesterday, I performed the synthesis of tert-butyl chloride from tert-butyl alcohole in my practical organic chemistry class. However, I only obtained a relatively low yield of about 30 %. Since I used more water and sodium hydrogen carbonate solution for the washing steps than recommended (I misread the instruction), my guess is, that some of the product was hydrolysed back to tert-butyl alcohol.

Is this a reasonable explanation for my low yield?

Comment: Yes, hydrolysis or elimination is likely. Washing with water or NaHCO3 solution is OK for a primary chloride but not recommended for a _tertiary_halide as you have sadly discovered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the instruction, the product (about 10 g of crude tert-butyl chloride) is washed 3 times with 5 ml of a saturated NaHCO3 solution and 3 times with 5 ml of water. Sadly, I misread the instruction and used 50 ml of each.

Comment: If you got your answer, feel free to self answer it. Self answer are appreciated and it also help future readers.

Comment: T-butyl chloride is known to be hydrolysed slowly by cold water. See the Org. Syn prep (1928) vol8 p50